# Generate Poisson process using R

Tags: r, statistics, poisson, stochastic-process

I want to generate a process where in every step there is a realisation of a Poisson random variable, this realisation should be saved and then it should be realize the next Poisson random variable and add it to the sum of all realisations before. Furthermore there should be a chance that in every step this process stops. Hope that makes sense to you guys... Any thought is appreciated!

Comment: Down-vote deserves a comment. So, whoever you are, please write why you down-voted so that OP can learn on how to improve his questions.

Answer (score 7):

More compactly, pick a single geometrically distributed random number for the total number of steps achieved before stopping, then use `cumsum` to sum that many Poisson deviates:

```
stopping.prob <- 0.3  ## for example
lambda <- 3.5         ## for example
n <- rgeom(1,1-stopping.prob)+1  ## constant probability per step of stopping
cumsum(rpois(n,lambda))
```

Comment: now I wonder whether there's a closed-form answer for this probability distribution ... I'm too busy/lazy to look it up in Pielou or Bailey, but it might make a good CrossValidated question ...

Answer (score 1):

You are very vague on the parameters of your simulation but how's this?

Lambda for random Poisson number.

```
lambda <- 5
```

This is the threshold value when the function exits.

```
th <- 0.999
```

Create a vector of length 1000.

```
bin <- numeric(1000)
```

Run the darn thing. It basically rolls a "dice" (values generated are between 0 and 1). If the values is below `th`, it returns a random Poisson number. If the value is above `th` (but not equal), the function stops.

```
for (i in 1:length(bin)) {
    if (runif(1) < th) {
        bin[i] <- rpois(1, lambda = lambda)
    } else {
        stop("didn't meet criterion, exiting")
    }
}
```

Remove zeros if any.

```
bin <- bin[bin != 0]
```

You can use `cumsum` to cumulatively sum values.

```
cumsum(bin)
```

Comment: it would be more efficient to generate all the `runif()` and `rpois()` first, then see which is first uniform number `< th` and retain only that many elements of the rpois values. Or even just do the `runif()` step, work out how many random poisson numbers you need and generate only that many. Also better to initiate loops with `i in seq_along(bin)`.

Comment: why are you removing zeros?  they're legitimate draws from a Poisson distribution ...